# Typescript 0.8.2 turn off compile-onsave

Tags: typescript

I've installed TypeScript 0.8.2 ... the compile-on-save feature is introduced. I'm not a fan of it since it introduces lagging on all kinds of actions in the solution explorer like renaming a file ...
I turned off both checkboxes in the options, but it keeps compiling and saving non-changed ts files...

Any thoughts on how to make it stop?

Comment: Are you using Web Essentials?

Comment: Nope ... vs2012... webexpress!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [0.8.2 release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/21/announcing-typescript-0-8-2.aspx), you can toggle compile on save using the following instructions.

Open Tools > Options dialog.

Expand Text Editor > Languages > TypeScript

Select Project

Tick or untick the "Compile on Save" options.

[image: Options Dialog]